# How to use map on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using this data set to listData state in React:

```
[
   {
      "Key": "Anchorage TAC 82.tif",
      "LastModified": "2019-04-07T03:25:51.000Z",
      "ETag": "\"9f904f2219d1edf3fa39b171c98de924-6\"",
      "Size": 28135199,
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
   },
   {
      "Key": "CSA-L01.pdf",
      "LastModified": "2019-04-07T03:25:36.000Z",
      "ETag": "\"90f166238ae6b1f64120e984be743ba4\"",
      "Size": 3406742,
      "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
   }
]
```

How can I map the Key values into a drop downlist.  I've tried:

```
<select>
    <option>Please select a file:</option>
        {Object.keys(this.state.listData).map(val =>
        <option value={val.Key}>{val.Key}</option>) }
</select>
```

and it's not working.  I'm getting a blank drop down list.

Answer (score 2):

`listData` is an array and `Object.keys(this.state.listData)` will return array of indexes `[0,1,2..]`
.You need to remove `Object.keys()` and apply `map()` directly on `listData`

```
<select>
    <option>Please select a file:</option>
        {
           this.state.listData.map(val =>(
              <option value={val.Key}>{val.Key}</option>
           ) 
        }
</select>
```

Comment: When I try this I get "this.state.listData.map is not a function"

Comment: @Rupp How your state looks like. `listData` is an array right?